# Are nuclear processes inside the Sun's core affected by gravitational time dilation?

Tags: gravity, nuclear-physics, time-dilation

Is it right that nuclear processes inside the Sun's core could be affected by gravitational time dilation?

Comment: Yes but only by a tiny amount. This can be seen through the gravitational redshifting of photons coming from the sun (which are by-products of fusion reactions). Their frequencies only redshift by a factor of about $10^{-6}$. Gravitational time dilation and redshifting are essentially one in the same. See [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_redshift) for more.

Comment: This is an answer not a comment.

Comment: I should add  to @ArturodonJuan comment that it is our *observation* of the nuclear process. The process itself is *not affected*, which is what we *assume* when we measure the redshift  of spectral lines.